# getPressure always returning 1.0

Tags: android, pressure, motionevent

Does anyone have any idea why `getPressure()` returns always `1.0`?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        System.out.println(event.getPressure());

        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone have any idea why getPressure() returns always 1.0?

The typical touchscreen / input device has no way to measure pressure. You either don't press and get no touch event or you press and get a touch event with value 1.

Comment: That is not true. Touchscreen devices can calculate pressure basing on size of contact area, which works well for fingers.

Comment: @Skiba +1 I guess I was wrong about that. Capacitive and resistive touchscreens can determine an area / strength but for values other than 1 and 0 to appear they have to evaluate and expose that data from touchscreen to low level driver to highlevel `TouchEvent`. And several simply don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/10pF8EUEuy0
Here's an answer about how getPressure and getSize() work in Android, I think this would help