# How to get finger touch size in Android

Tags: android, touch-event, motionevent

I am working on a feature where I need to shade the portion of bitmap where user swipes. I can get the start and end X coordinates but problem is getting height. Right now I am using MotionEvent.getTouchMajor() to get the finger touch ellipse major axis. But it doesn't return correct values for all devices like for Asus it returns correct values but it doesn't work on Samsung and Xiaomi etc.
I have tried getSize() and getPressure() but the return almost same values all the time. What should be my approach here? How do the paint applications work?

Comment: I don't think that all touch screens can measure touch size and pressure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068007/android-how-do-i-get-raw-touch-screen-information

Comment: In android there is no special hardware support to measure the pressure like in Iphone. please check with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12414826/6414107) answer

Comment: @VladMatvienko I know android uses some abstract method to calculate size and pressure. Which doesn't make any sense since they are always same. But how do paint like applications work?

Comment: Can you show such an app?

Comment: well for one there are photo editing apps like photo director where they have brush options.. And I was just checking other apps where they ask you to specify brush size. But that is not an option for me I guess. If any one has any solution plz share.

Comment: I don't think it's possible since touchscreen returns only the point of touch AFAIK.