# Is there any way in Android to measure precise touch pressure?

Tags: android

I am using event.getPressure(); to measure the pressure but it returns 0.0 or 1.0. Is there any way to measure precise pressure may be between 0 and 1 like 0.27, 0.45, 0.99...? I am writing a signature recognition program and using Canvas in Android. I am testing my program on Samsung Galaxy S5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getPressure always returning 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414491/getpressure-always-returning-1-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, if the device doesn't have physical hardware to sense pressure, that's all you got, 0, or 1. I think Huawei had some prototypes going on, but not anymore. Sorry, but this feature at the moment seems to live only in iOS's Force Touch.

Comment: Thanks DeadlyHigh